# Reactive Vue Data Does Not Render in Firefox Columns

Tags: firefox, vuejs3, css-multicolumn-layout

I've run into an extremely strange problem while developing a Vue SPA in Firefox (v89.0.1). Reactive data will not render on the page when it is contained within columns. Here is an example:

```
<template>
  <div style="column-count: 2">

    <div style="break-inside: avoid;">
      Column 1
    </div>

    <div style="break-inside: avoid;">
      Column 2 
      <div v-if="test">{{ test }}</div>
    </div>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      test: ''
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.test = 'tested';
    }, 2000);
  }
};
</script>
```

In Chrome, the word "tested" is correctly rendered in the second column. In Firefox the word "tested" does not immediately appear, but it will appear later if the window is resized. The issue is resolved if the column-count style is removed.

Is this a known issue and, if so, does anyone have a suggested work around? Really scratching my head on this. (Note: I'm using column-count to create a masonry layout, so I can't easily substitute another grid solution.)